# Change value on CellValueChanged Event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, devexpress

I am trying to change value of a cell if any other cell gets edited because I want to have an EditedAt cell in my Database and grid. I tried it with this event but it only saves the values without changing the date:

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColumnView tmpView = gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView;

        if (!tmpCellValueChanged && tmpView.UpdateCurrentRow())
        {
            tmpCellValueChanged = true;
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Model_EditedAt", DateTime.Now);
            tbModellTableAdapter1.Update(fahrzeugverwaltung_ColinDataSet1);
            tmpCellValueChanged = false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GridView.UpdateCurrentRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.UpdateCurrentRow.method) method should be called to post a focused modified row back to an underlying data source. I would recommend reviewing the [Post Data to an Underlying Data Source](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1082/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Binding/Post-Data-to-an-Underlying-Data-Source) help article where it is described how to deal with database updates.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q322494/changing-value-on-cellvaluechanging-event)

On the CellValueChanging event, call the table view's CommitEditing method. Thus, changes will be accepted without changing focus, and the CellValueChaned event will fire.

```
    private void TableView_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e) 
    {    
         ((TableView)sender).CommitEditing();
    }
```